# A comparison betwen "aid", "help" and "relief"

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

I have had a look on the definitions of these three similar words in dictionaries, but unfortunately I cannot differentiate between them! For more clarification I have provided you with a sentence using them where I cannot distinguish their meanings:

> - He held a concert **in aid of the** earthquake-stricken people.
> - He held a concert **for** earthquake-stricken people **relief**.
> - He held a concert **in order to help** earthquake-stricken people.

‎
Or

> - He gets around **with the aid of** a walking stick.
> - He gets around **with the help of** a walking stick.

As another example I don't know what to say in the following sentence to sound natural:

> - I hope I can do that **with your help / with your aid / etc.**

The only think that strikes me is that:

> - **Aid** and **relief** --- are more about the situation that someone is in need while **help** can be used in any circumstance.

Please let me know about them. 
‎
**Added:** 
 some other structures that I'm not sure which one sounds natural:

> - She went **to the aid of** a man trapped in his car.
> - She went **to the help of** a man trapped in his car. 
>    
>     She went **to assist** a man trapped in his car.

Answer (score 3):

You are right that all three of these words are related - but I would say *help* and *aid* are closer in meaning to each other (see also: *assist*) while *relieve* (or *relief*) means something more like "remove something that causes suffering".

If there's a concert for earthquake victims ("earthquake-stricken people" is an unnatural phrase), the goal is probably to [raise money](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benefit_concert). You can phrase the sentence like:

> He held a concert to raise money for earthquake victims.
>
> He held a concert to benefit earthquake victims.
>
> He held a concert to benefit the earthquake relief effort.

To address your other sentences:

> He gets around with the aid of a walking stick.

This is fine.

> He gets around with the help of a walking stick.

This is also fine. (again, *relief* is different from *help* and *aid* and would not work here.)

> I hope I can do that with your help / with your aid / etc.

*aid* as a noun sounds a little awkward to me in this context. *help* or *assistance* would sound best.

Comment: Thank you @Mixolydian for the informative post on this thread. Just first of all I needed your permission to **add** a part at the end, while we are discussing the relevant topic here it seems it would be of more help later. Then I know about **raising money**, but I neede to know how can I use **help od aid** in that case.

Comment: Per [this NGram,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=help+of+a+walking+stick%2Caid+of+a+walking+stick&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chelp%20of%20a%20walking%20stick%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caid%20of%20a%20walking%20stick%3B%2Cc0) *with the **aid** of a walking stick* has always been more common than *with the **help** of a walking stick* (and as you point out, nobody ever says *with the **relief** of a walking stick*).

Comment: @A-friend you don't need my permission for anything! Since you added those other three sentences at the end of your post - "to assist" is fine. "to the aid of" and "to the help of" - no. Just "to help" or "to aid" in this context. In terms of holding a concert - it sounds more natural to me to be specific about how the concert will help those people, which is by raising money (even if that's obvious).