# Comparing the nouns "aid" and "help"

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

Please have a look the following self-made sentences and help me to find out whether any of the items sounds unnatural. If yes, then why?  I need to come to a conclusion based on the probable incorrect cases that you will define here:

> - 1-1- A good dictionary can be a good **aid**. 
>     1-2- A good dictionary can be a good **help**.

OR

> - 2-1- **Aid** forces are on the way. (a government official said through a phone call to an earthquake victim.) 
>     2-2- **Help** forces are on the way.

OR

> - 3-1- We will send **aid** to you as soon as possible. 
>     3-2- We will send **help** to you as soon as possible.

Comment: I rolled back your revision, as changing the text of the sentences made the answer you received incorrect in parts.

Comment: Thank you @Katy. I was changing the question and letting Edward know about it adding some extra information at the end of the thread. Well, I'll try to post it as a new thread, although they're so close concepts. :)

Comment: @ A-friend. Maybe try asking your clarification in the comments of the question answer, or editing to add additional examples instead of changing the examples you already gave. That way the topic can be together, but you don't create a situation where you change a correct sentence to an incorrect one and cause the answer to seem wrong or misleading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A comparison betwen "aid", "help" and "relief"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/209717/a-comparison-betwen-aid-help-and-relief)

Answer (score 1):

All six examples sound reasonable as U.S. English. "Aid" and "help" do have slightly different connotations here. "Aid" in this context usually refers to physical items - medical supplies, food, etc. "Help" in this context usually refers to action - people are arriving to assist, rescue, etc.

The above is true for the dictionary examples as well. The dictionary as "aid" refers to the object - the dictionary. The dictionary as "help" refers to its ability to assist the person in figuring something out.

Comment: Thank you @Edward Barnard, but I would appreciate it if you could analyze my provided items #1 and #2 by interpreting them. According to your explanations, there is something missing for me in "dictionary" and people who are going to be of help in terms of **aid/help forces**. For me, your definition can only be applicable to the items of the third group.

Comment: @A-friend - I edited to clarify the dictionary case.